# Splitting Strings In List

Tags: python, split

I have a list like ;

> list1 = ['ex1_a','ex2_b','ex3_b']

I want to split it like this to the new list ;

> newlist = ['ex1 a', 'ex2 b', 'ex3 b']

I try to do it like this but it didn't work. How can I do this?

```
for x in list1:
             newlist = " ".join(x.split("_"))
```

Comment: That doesn't look like you are splitting anything. It look like you are replacing `_` with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` instead `str.split`/`str.join`:

```py
list1 = ["ex1_a", "ex2_b", "ex3_b"]

newlist = [v.replace("_", " ") for v in list1]
print(newlist)
```

Prints:

```py
['ex1 a', 'ex2 b', 'ex3 b']
```

---

If you want to use `str.split`:

```py
newlist = [" ".join(v.split("_")) for v in list1]
```